# Isset POST is saying there is a value even without a post

Tags: php, forms

I'm trying to only display some content if values were posted to my page. I'm doing this using the following code:

```
if(isset($_POST)){
    echo "it is in here";
}
```

The value in the `echo` is appearing even when the page loads, why would that be?

Comment: Regardless of whether information was posted or not `$_POST` will always exist because it is a pre-set system array, you could try doing `if (count($_POST) > 0)`

Comment: Or check for the existence of a submit button in your form - it's a fairly standard way to do it... `if (isset($_POST['submitButton'])) { // ... }`

Comment: `$_POST` is always accessible to the receiving script since its automatically generated by PHP. If you want to check if your request was initiated by a submitted form its usually best to simply check for existence of a form's submit button.

Something like `if (isset($_POST['submit_form'])) { ... }`.

Comment: If I recall correctly this will display either a value is set or not, it would be better if you test the field you submit like this: 'if(isset($_POST['field_name']))'

Answer (score 2):

`$_POST` are always set, try `empty` function instead. Try this:

```
    if(!empty($_POST)){
        echo "it is in here";
    }
```

Comment: Not ideal - anyone could post `foo=bar` to your web page and have that content show up

Comment: yup, need to do some checking before content shows. for example, set a hidden input with secret name and value.

Answer (score 1):

`$_POST` is one of the `superglobals` in PHP [Superglobals - PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php)

`isset()` will return `TRUE` on any of them, since they are

> built-in variables that are always available in all scopes

according to the official manual.

You should either check

```
isset($_POST['a specific post parameter name'])
```

Or, check:

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST'
```

to determine.

Answer (score 0):

`$_POST` `isset` even if it's `empty`

You can use `!empty` (not empty), i.e.:

```
if(!empty($_POST)){
    echo "it is in here";
}
```

---

Although, you should normally check if a specific `$_POST` parameter `isset`, i.e.:

```
if(isset($_POST["something"])){
    echo "something is in here";
}
```

---

Resources:

[function.empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

[reserved.variables.post](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php)

[function.isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)